# How do I fix this "Constructor cannot be called on object type" error in flow?

Tags: flowtype

I'm having trouble figuring out the problem that flow is complaining about. I'm trying to allow the implementation of an API be changeable by storing the implementation class, then later instantiating it, however, flow complains when I call `new this.implKlass` saying that "Constructor cannot be called on object type". What is flow trying to tell me, and what am I conceptually missing about how flow works?

Example code below, and [flow try code](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCOAlgCpgC8YA3qgJBQB2hAFAJQBcYACgE5wAtiQDOeADwgAfAG4wqAL7oAxjACGIkWACSgnDFoMNWJsrDM2XXgOFjJU2mD54MAVz5MwARjlKlqVQ0tABE4MgALEiYAcy06ehI9GABpdU1uYnIZBmU4JhEMPldlDDg+VgBrNJEM0jJ2QzAmsHoMSJEAOkT9VKCqMCqguVRmsCV6ZTUYGEtG5om8grBezX620S6klZFs0dHc-IwwKKXqJjwkbY5dvfpnNw9jw46La5Hmv3RzpFCIqNjWLp9OwOpNppYZEA) here

```
/* @flow */

type ApiT = {
    fnA(): Promise<*>; 
}

// An implementation of the API
class Impl {
    async fnA(): Promise<*> { return 1; }
}

class DoThings {
    implKlass: ApiT;
    constructor(klass) {
        this.implKlass = klass; 
    }
    callA() {
        const Klass = this.implKlass;
        const inst = new Klass();
        return inst.fnA();
    }
}

new DoThings(Impl).callA();
```

Example output:

```
18:         const inst = new Klass();
                         ^ constructor call. Constructor cannot be called on
18:         const inst = new Klass();
                             ^ object type
13:     constructor(klass: ApiT) {
                        ^ property `fnA`. Property not found in
23: new DoThings(Impl).callA();
                 ^ statics of Impl
```

Comment: You need to decide if `ApiT` refers to an instance of a class, or a constructor function that creates that instance. Here you're using it as both.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh, thanks, that's the knowledge gap I was missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a small modification this works.

```
class DoThings {
    implKlass: Class<ApiT>;
    constructor(klass) {
        this.implKlass = klass; 
    }
    callA() {
        const Klass = this.implKlass;
        const inst = new Klass();
        return inst.fnA();
    }
}
```

The bug was you were writing `ApiT` instead of `Class<ApiT>`. `ApiT` would be an instance of a class, while `Class<ApiT>` is the class itself.

[Try flow link](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCOAlgCpgC8YA3qgJBQB2hAFAJQBcYACgE5wAtiQDOeADwgAfAG4wqAL7oAxjACGIkWACSgnDFoMNWJsrDM2XXgOFjJU2mD54MAVz5MwARjlKlqVQ0tABE4MgALEiYAcy06ehI9GABpdU1uAGE0kXFiclkGZTgmEQw+V2UMOD5WAGts9kMwZrB6DEiRADpE-VSgqjB6oLlUFrAlemU1GBhLJpbJ4tKwPs0B9tFupNWRGVGxlqKSjDAo5eomPCQdjj2D1uc3D1Pjzotb-ea-dEukUIiorFWLp9OxOlMZpY5MBgGAAPK1VC-MD-SIxESsQJrABCagAJrQFOxobCAKJ8AR8MAAWjAeLgeBETAA5CdBGoMMpwmB2gQ8hRsPggA)

Comment: Thanks! It would be nice if that was actually documented instead of being left as a "todo". I see it's in progress though: https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/2983

Answer (score 1):

`ApiT` describes an object type, not a class type. An instance of the `Impl` class satisfies the `ApiT` type, but the class `Impl` itself does not. You cannot call `Impl.fnA()`, for example.

I'm not sure if there is any way to pass around constructors like this. However you can accomplish basically the same thing by using a factory function:

```
type ApiT = {
    fnA(): Promise<*>; 
}

type ApiTFactory = () => ApiT;

class Impl {
    async fnA(): Promise<*> { return 1; }
}

class DoThings {
    factory: ApiTFactory;
    constructor(factory: ApiTFactory) {
        this.factory = factory; 
    }
    callA() {
        const factory = this.factory;
        const inst = factory();
        return inst.fnA();
    }
}

new DoThings(() => new Impl()).callA();
```

[tryflow link](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCOAlgCpgC8YA3qgJBQB2hAFAJQBcYACgE5wAtiQDOeADwgAfAG4wqAL7ps+IqTIAxAIYBjDHD5YqYDlSlryM9DphaRIsAElBOGLQZ2sTHWGZsuvALCYpLmNGB8eBgArnxMYACMckpKqDZ2DgAicGQAFiRMAOYOdIy6+obcxOTaegZYVvQ6cEwiGHzRdXysUOX1Veq1FVjs7mDjYPQY+SIAdL1dRtQLw3KoE2BKTVowMP5jE00tbb59hsbTovNnDesbE82tGGAFJ8s3HFb3k5ExcS9PeYsT53cYpdBMPBIbJ5ArFVimSjmSFIZyuDjsWY6HZ7T5AA)